# How to execute a script if windowsize gets too small?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What is wrong about this?

```
if ((window.innerWidth < 1170)) ? {
    alert("so eng hier!");
};
```

Comment: There is a questionmark, that's a syntax error right there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the obvious syntax error, the question mark, nothing. Maybe you mean to execute that block of code in the window's resize event?

```
window.onresize = function(event) {

    if ((window.innerWidth < 1170))  {
        alert("so eng hier!");
    };

}
```

Be careful with the alert as it will fire every time the window resize event is fired, so as you're trying to resize the window to make it bigger it'll keep popping up.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with it, but it will only fire when the page loads. If you want to have it happen if the user resizes the window WHILE viewing your site, add a listener.

```
window.onresize = resize();

var resize = function (){
    if (window.innerWidth < 1170){
        alert("so eng hier!");
    };
};
```

Oh right. What is that `?` doing in there? Check your `if` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It's only called once (presumably on page load). I think you're looking to bind to:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  // check window size here and react when it's too small.
});
```